# EventLog counting users

Tags: c#

Good day, I've been fiddling around with the Eventlog method, and with fiddling around I was able to count how many entry.replacementstrings[5] aka usernames would be there.

```
public int countUsers { get; set; }
public string User { get; set; }
public Users(int count, string name)
{
    countUsers = count;
    User = name;
}

public void getCountUsers()
{
    number = 0; //
    UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
    EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog(); 
    myNewLog.Log = "Security";
    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.InstanceId == 4624 && entry.TimeWritten.Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            if (UserList.Count > 0)
            {
                bool check = false;
                foreach (var user in UserList)
                {
                    if (user.User == entry.ReplacementStrings[5])
                    {
                        user.countUsers += 1;
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!check)
                {
                    Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                    UserList.Add(u);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
                UserList.Add(u);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void counter()
{

    var totalUsers = UserList.Sum(user => user.countUsers); 
    foreach (var user in UserList)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("There has been {0} users on {1}", user.countUsers, DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Is what I currently have. What I now want to be able to do is, add a regex to the writeline so it doesn't count the user SYSTEM.

I was able to do it with but that would print out every individual user, but instead I want the general/global idea of how many people were online at said date.

So I need to know how to do it with getting rid of the for each loop, and just getting the user.countUsers.

```
foreach (var user in UserList)
{
    Regex User = new Regex(@"SYSTEM");
    Match match = User.Match(user.User);
    if (!match.Success)
    {}
}
```

I now don't know how to call the variable so my regex works. Anyone know how to fix it, maybe possibly without a regex?

(Side note: I also need help with the fact that the EventLog is 2x, when it should be 1 by the ones that are legit. I would need to see how I would filter that)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Regex since the string you want to exclude is literal, you can use Linq:

```
foreach (var user in UserList.Where(u => u.User != "SYSTEM"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("There has been {0} users on {1}", user.countUsers, DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Comment: I should've been more clear my apologies.

 I don't want to use a for each. I don't need to know anymore how many times one user has been logged on, I need to know it generally. This would print out how many times a different user would have been logged on.

Comment: Then you may want to use a `Dictionary<string, int>` @308075